# SQL Query get all construction plans order by missing parts

Tags: mysql, sql

OK lets consider we have the following db shema:

```
ConstructionPlans
c_id

Part
p_id

PlanPart
c_id p_id
```

The Table Construction Plans has all the plans, Part has all the parts and PlanPart has an entry for every plan and part combination. I am trying to think of a query considering that you would want to get all the construction plans (literally all) and have them in order of the number of parts that are missing. I have all the parts I have in an array for this query. I would also like to be able to check all the missing parts for a plan later on (but I guess one would simply take alle the c_ids in PlanPart and substract with the other Query and a Where Clause with the parts one already has).
Thank you for your input :)

Comment: I can't see how you can possibly create this query.  Since PlanPart is the only thing that tells you if a part is necessary, if the part is missing you have no possibly way to know.  

The exception would be if there's more to this schema, like, the number of parts that are actually in stock and you're looking for which plans have parts with an inventory count of zero.  If that's the case, it is absolutely doable but will require that you post your actual schema.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a column quantity in your Part table and a coulmn name in you ConstructionPlan table

```
select p.p_id from Part p, PlanPart pp, ConstructionPlan cp where p.quantity=0 and p.p_id=pp.p_id and cp.c_id = pp.c_id and cp.name = '<your plan name goes here>'
```

Comment: It's supposed to order the plans by the number of parts that are missing a part is missing if the quantity is lower than needed which would be statet in another row in the planpart table or if it is simply not there. I totally forgot the part with the quantity I'm sorry :(

Comment: Ok..getting there :) As user4932846 asked, what does "missing" mean? you can have an extra column saying "required_quanitity" and compare "available_quanitity", but you cannot have a part missing from the part table, because your definition of plan is based on the reference to parts.  So your definition of missing could be available_quantity < required_quanitity

Comment: well the available quantitiy is basically the quantity that the user inputs. So we have a two dimensional Array with a part and the quantity in which it is available but the form basically creates a new input field via Jquery autocomplete  so we only have the quantity for the parts that the user enters, if a part is not entered but the combination of part and plan exists in plan part than it is missing. To summarize this: We get a number of parts and the quantity of them from the user, if the quantity is lower that it is supposed to be or it ist noth there even though the combi exists its miss

Comment: We would double the awesomeness if we could also order it in this kind of way :plans with all parts there and enough quantity>plans with 1 part missing>plans with 2 parts missing but with 2 part not having enough quantity>plans with 1 part missing completely but I would be happy without it aswell :)